# inputAccessoryView issue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikeyboard, inputaccessoryview

When a user taps a button, the view dims with a black view and a form appears that is attached to a keyboard using inputAccessoryView. It is similar to the Instagram keyboard when you want to make a new collection on IOS. I'm having an issue, however, that sometimes when you press the button, only the black dim view covers the screen and the keyboard doesn't appear. I don't know what the problem is because sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't. Here is my code right now:

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 250))
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        blackView.frame = window.frame
        blackView.alpha = 0
        window.addSubview(blackView)
        window.addSubview(containerView)
        setupAllViews(container: containerView, field: listNameField, button: listButton, titleSeperator: titleSeperator, textSeperator: textSeperator, titleView: listViewTitle)
        blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissBlackView)))
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.blackView.alpha = 1
            containerView.alpha = 1
        }, completion: nil)
        listNameField.inputAccessoryView = containerView
        listNameField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: Are you testing it on simulator or on a real device? In the simulator keyboard may not appear sometimes, but you can force to open it by pressing ⌘+K.

Comment: @Woof it has happened on both platforms.

Comment: And what if you will add listNameField.becomeFirstResponder() inside animation completion brackets?